# Django Rest Framework: How to generate sequence numbers

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

In my projects, there is a unique random number that is auto-generated through a function, but the scenario is I want a sequential number for each entry.

```
def generate_unique_key(length):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for _ in range(length))

def get_unique_key():
        while User.objects.filter(learner_number=unique_id).exists():
            unique_id = ("NO" + generate_unique_key(length=3)).upper()
        return unique_id
```

how to change the above functions to generate sequential numbers for each entry? Like

```
userA: NO001
userB: NO002
```

Comment: so you can generate upto 999 unique numbers only

Comment: yes, have any suggestions?

Comment: each entry means total 999 entries can be made beyound that you cannot yes?.Can you clarify the question. What actually you need. In above code User model is filtering with unique id from where it is initialised

Comment: If I increase the "length", I can add as many users as I need, but I do not know how to initialize and generate a sequential number using this function.

Comment: you can use a file and increase that.